# Null Sets in "P - Almost Surely" Proofs

Tags: probability, measure-theory

We receive the definition of P-AS convergence as follows:

On $(\Omega, \scr A,\rm P)$, a property holds true P-almost surely if $\exists$ set $N|[(P(N)=0) \forall \omega \in \Omega \text{ such that the result does not hold true}]$.

Unfortunately this definition is pretty semantic and thus I was wondering then if, for example, $N=\emptyset$ is a valid "null set" one could use in order to prove P-AS of some property.

Comment: Yes, $\emptyset$ is a valid null set, because for every measure $P$, $P(\emptyset) = 0$ by definition of measures. If the null set is $\emptyset$, that just means that the property holds for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very rarely will $N=\emptyset$. If so, we say that the property holds $P$-surely.

The set $N$ will depend on the specific circumstance. For example, if you pick a number uniformly from $[0,1]$ then $P$-almost surely the number will be irrational. The $N$ in this case are the rational numbers in $[0,1]$.